# add to list (identifying whether input is a prime number)

Tags: python

Trying to write a function 'prime_check(number)' to test if an argument is a prime number

The number_of_factors for a given number should only be 1 (the given number itself) and '1', which is already excluded in the while statement

Having trouble adding a variable to the list "set_of_factors"
Tried to debug in Thonny, which says that set_of_factors = none

```
def prime_checker(number):

    set_of_factors=[]
    number_of_factors=len(set_of_factors)
    f=2

    while number > 1 and f<=number:
        if number%f == 0:
            set_of_factors.insert(0,1)
            f+=1            
        else:
            f+=1              
    if number_of_factors==1:
        print("It is a prime number")
    else:
        print("It is not a prime number")

n = int(input("Check this number: "))
prime_checker(number=n)
```

Comment: Move `number_of_factors=len(set_of_factors)` to after the `while` loop.

Comment: In fact it is better not to have that variable at all, and just use `len(set_of_factors)` directly.

Comment: Thanks to both, that solved it. 
Could I get some critique on how to ask better questions?

Answer (score -1):

Prime numbers have two factors, one and itself. Ex. 5's factors would be (1, 5)

Also istead if ".insert" use ".append"

```
    def prime_checker(number):

    set_of_factors=[]
    number_of_factors=len(set_of_factors)
    f=2
    while number > 1 and f<=number:
        if number%f == 0:
            set_of_factors.insert(0)
            f+=1            
        else:
            f+=1              
    if number_of_factors==2:
        print("It is a prime number")
    else:
        print("It is not a prime number")
```

Comment: The factor checking loop starts at 2, so it deliberately ignores the factor of 1.

Comment: *number_of_factors* always value 0, to compare with 2 is as false as to compare with 1